# nginx : enabling gzip compression based on hostname

Tags: nginx, gzip

I have a single machine running nginx serving http traffic for multiple domains(using same Lua codebase). For some of the domains I would like to enable gzip compression. Is it possible to enable gzip compression for specific set of domains? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely if you take a look at the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip) you can see that it is acceptable to place `gzip` in any of the following levels `http, server, location, if in location` and as the domain is defined at the `server` level using `server_name` we can place gzip along side it.

First check your `nginx.conf` file for `gzip on;` if it is present remove it.

You then need to create a conf file and define where you want to use gzip.

```
server {
  server_name www.myexample.com;
  listen 80;
  gzip off;
}

server {
  server_name www.myotherexample.com;
  listen 80;
  gzip on;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is. You should have a server block for each host name, just use

```
gzip on;
```

or

```
gzip off;
```

Inside each server block. The [documentation can be found here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip). The only snag is if you've used some kind of wildcard, or don't have a server block per domain.

eg

```
server {
  server_name www.example.com;
  listen 80;
  root /what/ever;
  gzip on;
}

server {
  server_name www.example2.com;
  listen 80;
  root /what/ever2;
  gzip off;
}
```

If this doesn't make sense post your nginx configuration file and your site file(s) and we can take a look.

Comment: Ah beat me to it

Comment: It's not a competition :-)